# ImageView not showing up on Android

Tags: android

When I try to show an image using ImageView on my emulator, it shows up.
Once I add a button, the image doesn't show up.

I don't know if this helps, but my XML when it's working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually the problem is that you didn't define the orientation of `LinearLayout.`  By default it is horizontal, and you have set `layout_width` of the button to `fill_parent`, so it fills the whole area.  You should either set the orientation to vertical or set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in the button tag.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have to do is to make the buttons' `layout_width` to `wrap_content`

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```